# Importing huge excel (xlsx) into SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, xlsx

I have excel file about 300MB+ in size. When I tried loading it with conventional excel source and SQL destination it keep on spinning. Not loaded even a row.

Is there any way to load huge excel file to SQL Server using SSIS? possible to reduce into small chunks (batch processing) ?

Comment: Does your processs actually work if you limit the xlsx file to fewer rows? I'd suggest trying just 100!

Comment: ya working fine with sample files

Comment: does it work if you export the Excel file to csv and then try to import the csv with SSIS?

Comment: reading itself issue i think, anyway will try and give a comment

Comment: Excel can have nasty hidden characters in the cells like CR or LF or TABs etc...  If unquoted, these can play havoc with imports...SAVE AS a CSV file, then import the CSV into SQL and standby for errors, which will at least tell you which row has problem characters

Comment: You should be able to search and replace 'problem' characters within Excel.  (Assuming this is the problem, which is my educated guess)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is a HUGE Excel file.  I didn't know that you could actually save a file that big.  Anyway, if I were you, I would convert it to .xlsb, which is binary, and may be as small as 1/4 the size of a .xlsx file.  Or, save it as a cvs file, and load the csv into SQL Server.  You can bulk insert a csv file into SLQ Seerver very easily using a concept like this.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO
--Drop the table to clean up database.
DROP TABLE CSVTest
GO
```

See the links below for a few ideas of how to do this.

https://archive.is/RATG#selection-443.0-561.3

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/20/sql-server-importing-csv-file-into-database-sql-in-sixty-seconds-018-video/

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/02/sql-server-import-csv-into-database-transferring-file-content-into-a-database-table-using-csvexpress/

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/

Comment: This will work very well, unless there are format problems with the CSV file (coming from hidden problems in the Excel worksheet)